# Melt/unpivot a dataset with multiple groups of values

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, pandas-melt

I'm trying to convert a dataframe in Python, and I am stuck because I don't know exactly how to phrase what I want to do (which makes searching for it difficult). It seems like I need a combination of unstack and pivot. I can explain it with an example though, hopefully. I have a dataframe with this shape:

| userid | GroupA_measure1 | GroupA_measure2 | GroupB_measure1 | GroupB_measure2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 65 | 70 | 45 | 50 |
| 002 | 96 | 89 | 12 | 8 |
| 003 | 12 | 14 | 38 | 40 |

and I want to convert this to this format:

| userid | measure | groupA | groupB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1 | 65 | 45 |
| 001 | 2 | 70 | 50 |
| 002 | 1 | 96 | 12 |
| 002 | 2 | 89 | 8 |
| 003 | 1 | 12 | 38 |
| 003 | 2 | 14 | 40 |

I can unstack the whole df using `pd.melt(df, id_vars =['userid'])` which put all values in separate rows, but I want to keep separate columns for the values of GroupA and GroupB.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) with extract numbers from `measure` column by [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df1 = pd.wide_to_long(df, 
                      stubnames=['GroupA','GroupB'], 
                      i='userid', 
                      j='measure', sep='_', suffix=r'\w+').reset_index()

df1['measure'] = df1['measure'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)
```

Or convert not `_` columns first, split all columns with `_` and reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), last also extract digits:

```
df1 = df.set_index('userid')
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df1 = df1.rename_axis((None, 'measure'), axis=1).stack().reset_index()
df1['measure'] = df1['measure'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)
print (df1)
  userid  measure GroupA GroupB
0    001        1     65     45
1    002        1     96     12
2    003        1     12     38
3    001        2     70     50
4    002        2     89      8
5    003        2     14     40
```

Last if necessary sorting by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df1 = df1.sort_values('userid', ignore_index=True)
print (df1)
  userid  measure GroupA GroupB
0    001        1     65     45
1    001        2     70     50
2    002        1     96     12
3    002        2     89      8
4    003        1     12     38
5    003        2     14     40
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is with the [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), using the `.value` placeholder:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df.pivot_longer(index="userid", 
                names_to=(".value", "measure"), 
                names_pattern=r"(.+)_*(\d)"
               )

   userid measure  GroupA_measure  GroupB_measure
0     001       1              65              45
1     002       1              96              12
2     003       1              12              38
3     001       2              70              50
4     002       2              89               8
5     003       2              14              40
```

The names_pattern is a regex to split the columns. The `.value` keeps the part of the column associated with it as header, while the number extracted via the regex goes into the `measure` column.